# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer

Tags: java, maven, xml-parsing, soapui, cglib

I am, via SOAPUI, converting a handful of fields into a java object, then using this information to call a webservice for a save functionality. The conversion from SOAPUI to java object seems to work fine. I can view the object in my debugger and it looks precisely similar to my JUNIT. Still might be problematic.

In addition, i'm able to hit this service directly and save via JUNIT with no problems. The problems only arise after the XML is parsed into a java object AND the service is called (It seems to parse fine, once again) via SOAPUI (integration).

This is obviously some sort of parsing issue with XML -- > java pojo and/or a library issue.

Any Idea? My compile time libs,  seemingly associated, are as follows:

1. asm - 4.0 is compiled (overwriting 5.0.4 due to dependency)
2. cglib 2.2
3. cglib-nodep 3.2.2

   ERROR: BUSINESS_EVENT REQUEST_ID= ELAPSED_TIME="17" END="2017-11-10 07:49:39,051" ENV_DESCRIPTOR="a" ENVIRONMENT="N/A" EXCEPTIONCLASS="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" EXECUTION_ID="" ROUTING_INTENTION="production" SERVER_IP="****" SESSION_ID="429b6099-98a6-4bae-8cdb-5ba295e9b223" START="2017-11-10 07:49:39,034" SUCCESS="false" THREAD_ID="tomcat-http--7" TRANS_ID="*******" USER_ID="anonymous" TRACE=**"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.CGLIBEnhancedConverter.canConvert(CGLIBEnhancedConverter.java:67)**
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.lookupConverterForType(DefaultConverterLookup.java:60)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:68)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)

<-- company specific stack trace packages -->

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following dependency seemed to magically fix everything. I left all of my old libs intact

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
```